# Using Java to set the focus to a non Java application in Windows

Tags: java, windows

I would like to write an application who creates input for a non-Java application in Windows. With the Robot class it's easy to generate the input, but I need to set the focus to another application's text box and enter the text over there.

Don't worry I'm not trying to write something malicious, I just want to use Java to "extend" an old application written in Delphi.

Comment: An alternative option is that my Java application never gets the focus, so that the windows application has the focus and when you click a button on the Java application the focus is never lost in the original window. I have no idea if that's possible?

Comment: for those coming to this question via google, on OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859733/set-focus-of-any-application-with-java-osx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CMDOW](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/) is a command line utility which allows you to perform various window actions such as activating/deactivating, listing, minimising/maximising etc.

**Alternatively**, you can write a VBScript to activate another application. For example:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.AppActivate("Firefox")
```

Then use `Runtime.exec` from your Java app to execute the script.

This will help you activate another application.

**However**, it will be much more difficult if you want to focus on a textbox within the other application and write some text.

Comment: just have to say that I like CMDOW but I noticed 2 problems.. very slow.. on my overloaded thermal throttled system - ordering a new fan now - so for most users don't know if it will be noticeable, however nircmd worked much faster.. so just letting people know nircmd is an option too - doesn't support wildcards but you can specify if substring match or from start or from end of title. Also I couldn't get it to activate multiple windows with the same substring, nircmd could do this.. so for these 2 reasons I chose nircmd instead..

Comment: @dogbane do you know something similar for linux os?

Answer (score 8):

Configure a delay otherwise it won't work:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
r.delay(10); //set the delay
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

Answer (score 7):

Detecting a special application and bringing that one to the front might require a native helper, but for the moment you could send <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to activate the "next" application

This works:

```
public void switchFocus() {
  try {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  } catch(AWTException e) {
    // handle
  }
}
```

you just need to implement a convenience method to map chars (from a String) to key event values... (or find some existing solution)

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, there is possible to do it with AppleScript. AppleScript is integrated to system, so it will be always functional.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html

You need only detect you are on mac and has name of the application.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] args = { "osascript", "-e", "tell app \"Chrome\" to activate" };
            Process process = runtime.exec(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add enough delay for the application to fully initialize and gain focus.

Here's a basic working example... [Andreas_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105224/andreas-d) is correct that you need to emulate the system key to switch between programs... (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on OS X)

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class RobotSample {

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782231
        private static Integer[] KEY_CODES = { VK_S, VK_T, VK_A, VK_C, VK_K, VK_O, VK_V, VK_E, VK_R, VK_F, VK_L,VK_O, VK_W, VK_DECIMAL, VK_C, VK_O, VK_M, VK_SLASH, VK_Q, VK_U, VK_E, VK_S, VK_T, VK_I, VK_O, VK_N, VK_S, VK_SLASH, VK_4, VK_7, VK_8, VK_2, VK_2, VK_3, VK_1, VK_ENTER };

        public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

                runtime.exec( "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" );

                robot.keyPress( VK_ALT );
                robot.keyPress( VK_TAB );
                robot.keyRelease( VK_ALT );
                robot.keyRelease( VK_TAB );

                //Chill a sec...
                robot.delay( 1000 );

                for(int i = 0; i <  KEY_CODES.length; ++i) {
                    robot.keyPress( KEY_CODES[i] );
                    robot.keyRelease( KEY_CODES[i] );
                    robot.delay( 80 );
                    }

            } catch( AWTException e ) {
                e.getMessage();
            }

        }

    }
```