# Java Robot class won't interact with an application?

Tags: java

I've been reading up on this and haven't found an answer that has made sense to me.

I'm trying to write a program in Java to interact with an application to see if I can write a program to play a video game for me. The game is on my computer.

Here is an excerpt of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

    run.exec("open /Applications/OpenEmu.app");

    try {

        Robot robot = new Robot();


        System.out.println("Waiting 5 Seconds");
        //robot.delay(5000);

        System.out.println("Pressed X");
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        //Starts an easy mode game
```

It opens the application fine, and in something like notepad, it will type XXXX, but it won't do so for the game?

I've assigned the 'x' key on my keyboard as a command button for the game. My guess is that the 'x' press is internal. All help is appreciated!

Comment: I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924246/java-robot-class-add-focus-to-a-specific-running-application recently and maybe am just missunderstanding it?

Additionally, I am on a Mac if that means anything

Comment: Aside from micormuncher's answer, a window can only respond to key events if it has keyboard focus, something to keep in mind

Comment: Just a theory, but it is possible that some games aren't using the system default input interface. For instance if I remember correctly, games in Windows using DirectX won't use the windows API for keyboard input, but something different (DirectInput). I don't know for mac, it might be the same problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to simulate input, try add robot.keyRelease as well. Javadoc for robot says for keyPress "Presses a given key. The key should be released using the keyRelease method."

```
    System.out.println("Pressed X");
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    ...
```

Also remember this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html "Note that some platforms require special privileges or extensions to access low-level input control. "