# Set focus of any application with Java (OSX)?

Tags: java, macos, focus

How can I set the focus (e.g. cmd+tab) of an arbitrary application (Java or not) from a Java program, on OSX?

Looking for an answer to this question, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782231/using-java-to-set-the-focus-to-a-non-java-application-in-windows), but it doesn't really help for OSX.

**EDIT:** one possibiltiy seems to be to use something like [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/), and a [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to send it keypresses with modifiers.  I'd prefer something more portable, though, that requires less setup to make changes after it's compiled....

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "the focus of an application"? Do you mean you want to make another application frontmost, or you want to set the keyboard focus to a particular text field that happens to be in another application, or what?

Comment: no need to focus in a specific textfield (as described by the poster of the other question i linked to); just focus as with cmd+tab.

Comment: `Runtime.exec("open /path/to/Whichever.app")` should reactivate the app if it's running already. It will however also start an app if it's not.

Comment: @millimoose -- beautiful.  please post this as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to reactivate an already running app using the [`open`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command that comes with OS X:

```
Runtime.exec("open /path/to/Whichever.app");
```

(Or some equivalent overload of that function.) This will also open an app if it's not running yet.

Comment: wish you would have answered 43 mins ago.

Comment: if there are any spaces in the app filename, Runtime.exec will break it apart into separate arguments.  using `Runtime.exec(String[])` fixes this:
`String[] cmd = { "open", appPath };`
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: @ericsoco Yup, that's why I mentioned "equivalent overload". I assumed  familiarity with the quirks of `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: That answer should have so many upvotes, 9 years later and still helping :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the javax.script API to run AppleScripts. So you can write a script along the lines of "tell application "WhateverApp" to activate", filling in your arbitrary application for WhateverApp, and it should do what you want.

Comment: interesting.  a little googling turned up a mailing list thread with some info on passing a param to an applescript: http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2008/Aug/msg00094.html

Comment: @ericsoco: You shouldn't need to pass a parameter for this particular task. Since you construct your AppleScript program as a string, just build it with the application name already in place.

Comment: sorry, i should have clarified -- my java application will need to switch between multiple applications.  will edit my question.

Comment: @ericsoco: I'm saying you could simply construct a string for each application with the application name in the appropriate place. E.g. `String program = "Tell application \"" + appName + "\" to activate"`. I mean, whatever works for you, obviously. That just seemed like the simplest solution to me if passing parameters is difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Chuck's answer tipped me off to `osascript`, so I decided to give it a shot straight from the command line.  Managed to get it working with [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), [`osascript`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html), and AppleScript.

Java launches an AppleScript and passes it the application name, using `osascript` from the command line, via `Runtime.exec()`:

```
try {
    List<String> shellCommandList = new ArrayList<String>();
    shellCommandList.add("osascript");
    shellCommandList.add("activateApplication.scpt");
    shellCommandList.add(appName);

    String[] shellCommand = (String[])shellCommandList.toArray(new String[0]);
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCommand);

    // if desired, pipe out the script's output
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String cmdOutStr = "";
    while ((cmdOutStr = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(cmdOutStr);
    }

    // if desired, check the script's exit value
    int exitValue = p.waitFor();
    if (exitValue != 0) {
        // TODO: error dialog
        System.err.println("Invalid application name: "+ appName);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the AppleScript uses a run handler to capture the incoming argument:

```
on run (arguments)
    set appName to (item 1 of arguments)
    tell application appName to activate
    return 0
end run
```

Comment: Another tip for folks that might be interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12613124/553524