# Sending KeyEvents to a Process

Tags: java, process, keyevent, processbuilder, awtrobot

I am trying to send keyboard commands to a game emulator from my Java program, I know how to set up the `process` from `processbuilder` and run the process.

However, I'm still having trouble with sending the process keyboard commands from my `Robot`.

An `InputStream` won't be much help as I need to send `keyEvents` such as pressing the 'y' button and having the emulator respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need your application/console window to be the active window for the key presses to be sent there. I suggest as a first test, run your java app but add a 10 second delay before starting the key presses. Then, click manually and activate the emulator window and wait for the automated key presses to start.

Also, add a 500 MS delay between key presses (e.g. using Thread.sleep() ) because multiple key presses do not work well.

Also See: [Using Java to set the focus to a non Java application in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782231/using-java-to-set-the-focus-to-a-non-java-application-in-windows)