# How to change focused window to specific windows in java?

Tags: java, audio, javafx, focus

How do you change the focused window with java? I want to press a button to pause and start my Spotify music. Since i found there is no way to controls system volume, i found Spotify has shortcuts which can be use to pause and start music.The VBs code below doesn't work:

```
Dim ObjShell :Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ObjShell.AppActivate("spotify")
```

Spotify's name changes when the song is playing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Java to set the focus to a non Java application in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782231/using-java-to-set-the-focus-to-a-non-java-application-in-windows)

Comment: @azurefrog The VBs code doesn't work: